# Deleting an item from an array using arraycopy

Tags: java, arrays

I am having problems deleting an item from my array using arraycopy.
I have two methods find (which locates the index of the item to be deleted) and 
delete (which does the deletion).
It doesn't delete anything.  Thank you in advance.

```
 public void find(Comparable value2){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Comparable value = value2;

    if (empty() == true){
        System.out.println("The array is empty");

    }
    else{
    int bsValue = Arrays.binarySearch(sa,value);
    System.out.println("The index is: " + bsValue);
    delete(bsValue);
    }
    }

 public void delete(int bs){
     int location = bs;   
     Comparable[] tempArray = new Comparable[sa.length -1];
     System.arraycopy(sa, 0, tempArray, 0, location);
     if (sa.length != location){
         System.arraycopy(sa, location +1 , tempArray, location, sa.length - location - 1);
     }      
}
```

Comment: Small note, you don't have to write `(empty() == true)`. You can just write `(empty())` (a way better).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocate `tempArray`, copy the data into it, and then abandon the reference. As a result, the original array (`sa`) stays exactly as it was.

Presumably you meant to make `sa` point to the new array:

```
sa = tempArray;
```

Comment: Thank you I changed it after your first comment. It works now. I was looking at that forever!

Answer (score 0):

create a new object of tempArray  by deep copying sa and that will do the job for you